# "Cannot determine the opposite position of: to" error in Compass 0.12.7

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, compass

Running Compass 0.12.7 (Alnilam) I'm running into this error several times repeated:

```
Running "compass:dev" (compass) task
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
Cannot determine the opposite position of: to
unchanged public/styles/sass/ie_only.scss
unchanged public/img/icons-s6ab39d30ab.png
overwrite public/styles/css/screen.css (2.484s)
```

It is something wrong with my gradients I take it, but what is going wrong here and how can I alleviate the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue on my project using compass 0.12.7 and unforuately the issue can only be solved by updating compass. The issue warning is caused when using the `linear-gradient` mixin with a position value of `to right` like in the following example:

```sass
div {
  @include background(linear-gradient(to right, red, blue));
}
```

This would be compiled to something like this (throwing the error you in your question):

```css
div {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, to right, to left, color-stop(0%, #ff0000), color-stop(100%, #0000ff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
}
```

Unforunately this is invalid CSS code. The correct output should be the following:

```css
div {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 50%, 100% 50%, color-stop(0%, #ff0000), color-stop(100%, #0000ff));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #0000ff);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #ff0000, #0000ff);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff0000, #0000ff);
}
```

The only way to fix it, is updating compass, as I said before.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't/don't want to update your sass, you can remove that "to" property.

Default sass gradient is vertical:

```
@include background(linear-gradient(red, blue));
```

To get horizontal:

```
@include background(linear-gradient(90deg, red, blue));
```